# Problem deploying Seam application in JBoss 6

Tags: deployment, jboss, seam, web.xml, jboss6.x

I'm trying to deploy a simple "hello world" Seam application on JBoss 6, and I'm getting these errors on the log:

```
Deployment "jboss.ejb3:application=helloworld,component=TimerServiceDispatcher,module=jboss-seam,service=EjbEncFactory" is in error due to the following reason(s): Described
Deployment "org.jboss.ejb.bean.instantiator/helloworld/jboss-seam/TimerServiceDispatcher" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'org.jboss.ejb.bean.instantiator/helloworld/jboss-seam/TimerServiceDispatcher' **
Deployment "jboss.naming:application=helloworld,component=TimerServiceDispatcher,module=jboss-seam" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.naming:application=helloworld,component=TimerServiceDispatcher,module=jboss-seam' **
Deployment "org.jboss.ejb.bean.instantiator/helloworld/jboss-seam/EjbSynchronizations" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'org.jboss.ejb.bean.instantiator/helloworld/jboss-seam/EjbSynchronizations' **
Deployment "jboss.ejb3:application=helloworld,component=EjbSynchronizations,module=jboss-seam,service=EjbEncFactory" is in error due to the following reason(s): Described
Deployment "jboss.naming:application=helloworld,component=EjbSynchronizations,module=jboss-seam" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.naming:application=helloworld,component=EjbSynchronizations,module=jboss-seam' **
```

Evidently the deployment process can't find `TimerServiceDispatcher` and `EjbSynchronizations` , but I registered them in `web.xml` :

```
 <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>helloworld/EjbSynchronizations/local</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>org.jboss.seam.transaction.LocalEjbSynchronizations</local>
    <ejb-link>EjbSynchronizations</ejb-link>
  </ejb-local-ref>

  <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>helloworld/TimerServiceDispatcher/local</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local>org.jboss.seam.async.LocalTimerServiceDispatcher</local>
    <ejb-link>TimerServiceDispatcher</ejb-link>
  </ejb-local-ref>
```

What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing? and notice that the deployer is looking for the components in `/helloworld/jboss-seam/TimerServiceDispatcher` and not in `/helloworld/TimerServiceDispatcher` (same thing with `EjbSynchronizations`)

Comment: Which version of seam are you running?

Comment: It's Seam 2.2.1.Final. I'm trying to run the helloworld example from the book "Seam Framework: Experience the Evolution of Java EE, 2nd Edition", downloaded from the book's [web site](http://solutionsfit.com/blog/books)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it was a problem with the packaging. The `jboss-seam.jar` library was in the lib directory inside the `.ear` file of the project; this no longer works in JBoss 6, as that file must now reside at the root level inside the `.ear`. Also, the location of `jboss-seam.jar` in `application.xml` must be adjusted accordingly.